# create a martix from a dataframe with a datetimeindex

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe that has monthly data. The index is a datetimeindex & the other column is a numeric column.

What I want to do is create a matrix where I have the 12 months across the top and the years as rows and the numeric value as the elements of the matrix.

Is there a clever way to do this without me looping?

Comment: `df.groupby([df.index.month, df.index.year])['col'].first().unstack()`

Comment: @QuangHoang thank you for you help, if you post the comment as an answer I can mark it as correct